# VSCode attach debug to nodejs which run on WSL

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I get error:
Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000ms - (reason: cannot connect to the target)

NodeJs v4.3.1 run on WSL.

The below is my launch.json

```
"type": "node",
"request": "attach",
"name": "Attach to WSL",
"port": 3000,
"address": "localhost",
"restart": true,
"protocol": "inspector",
"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/web-frontend",
"remoteRoot": "/mnt/c/workspace/.../web-frontend"
```

WSL uses the path from Windows so localRoot and remoteRoot are the same.

What am I missing so far?

Answer (score 0):

I created a VS Code extension: [WSL workspaceFolder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lfurzewaddock.vscode-wsl-workspacefolder), which will help you to automatically set the `remoteRoot` in your launch.json to the correct WSL path. For example my `launch.json`, based upon your file paths would look like below;

/vscode/launch.json

`{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Remote",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/web-frontend",
            "remoteRoot": "${command:extension.vscode-wsl-workspaceFolder}/web-frontend"
        }
    ]
}`

Then to start a debug session, in the WSL terminal enter `NODE_ENV=debug node --nolazy --inspect-brk=5858` before the path to the script you wish to debug.

However, you may run into problems using Node v4 because it does not support the 'inspector protocol'. I would strongly recommend you upgrade to a more recent version of Node. Currently v8 is the latest LTS version: [Node.js releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

Comment: Is there a way to have vscode ask for the port number?

Comment: Yes, this GitHub issue may help ["Dynamic" debug launch args in the UI #30588](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30588)